# R plot function: Increase size of legend scale tick labels

Tags: r, plot, raster

I am using `plot()` for some raster images. I want to increase the size of the legend scale tick labels. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the documentation for `raster::plot()`, any extra parameters passed to it are passed to `fields::image.plot()`. See: [image.plot](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/fields/versions/11.6/topics/image.plot)

Based on the answer to this: [Increase font size in legend of image.plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57055093/increase-font-size-in-legend-of-image-plot), you should be able to pass

```
axis.args = list(cex.axis = font_size)
```

as a parameter to your call to `plot()` to change the legend tick label size.